# Nested while loop doesnt work in r

Tags: r, while-loop

I have a while loop nested in another while loop, but it seem, that doesnt work ( the nested while works for only c=1 and not for 2,3,4,5...). Did I use While loop correctly or not?

this is my code:

```
while(c<90)
{
  while(r+window<=length(dat[,1]))
  {
    m<-acf(dat[r:(r+window),c],lag.max=32,plot=FALSE)$acf[-1]
    for(i in (1:32))
    {
      if(m[i]>l)
      {
        co<-co+1
      }
    }
    if(co>5)
    {
      row<-as.character(r)
      spalte<-as.character(c)
      pos<-rbind(row,spalte)
      stelle<-c("-",pos)
    }
  print(r)
  r<-r+30
  }
  c<-c+1
  print(c)
}
print(stelle)
```

Comment: What is the value of `r` and `window`?  Make sure that after the first iteration, the condition in the second `while` is still true.

Comment: Why don't you use `for` loops?

Comment: Add the line `browser()` just inside the first while loop and run step-by-step through your code checking the values of each of your variables. Also see http://www.stats.uwo.ca/faculty/murdoch/software/debuggingR/

Comment: It is super hard to tell what is going on without some example data. You could also tell us what is not working (what is the error, what are the expected results for the example data). I am guessing, however, that you want to accumulate results in `stelle`. I suspect that what you really want is `stelle<-c(stelle,'-',pos)`, so that you collect all results. Also, reset your `r` and `co` just before you enter the second `while`.

Answer (score 0):

$selectmatch_user=$DatabaseCo->dbLink->query("select * from register where status='Active' ");while($fetch_sel=mysqli_fetch_array($selectmatch_user))
{ $email=$fetch_sel['email'];
$gender=$fetch_sel['gender'];
$tt="SELECT * FROM register_view where  gender!='".$gender."' status!='Inactive' and status!='Suspended' ";
    $sqll123=$DatabaseCo->dbLink->query($tt);

```
while($fetch_matches_list=mysqli_fetch_array($sqll123))
```

{ $sqll="select id from sendmail where email='$email'"; this is is not send in mail
send email and message
}
}

> Blockquote

'

Comment: in this fist query select all actuve member and it's criteria to send email and second while fecth that data acording to first while id and in second while loop send email